# Why is the associated lookup field not on the dispform.aspx?

Tags: content-type, lookup-column, display-form

I have three lists:

- Events (calendar)
- Customer1 (custom list from scratch)
- Customer2 (custom list from template)

When I added the lookup of Customer1's ID and added the associated field "Title," both items were added to the Dispform.aspx and the content type.

However, when I added the lookup to Customer2's ID and added the associated field "Title," only the ID is showing on the Dispform.aspx and the contect type. I can't figure out how to fix this. I've done some searching here and online, but haven't found anything that seems to describe this same issue.

Comment: Does Customer2's LookUp field point to Events or Customer1?

Comment: I have the same problem please advice!
Urgent!
Even when a new lookup column is created the associated fields are not appearing on the list new item Form. I think this is due to the field is not added to the Item content type, how could I add those lookup fields to the content type?

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned that the Customer2 list was created from the template. 
If the list which was saved as a template has any look up columns during the save as template they will break -  so In the customer2 list you would have to delete the lookup columns and recreate them again.